# Align pgfplotstable in enumerate

Tags: vertical-alignment, pgfplotstable

I want to align a table created with `pgfplotstable` to the top in an `enumerate` environment, but instead it's aligned to the center. How can I fix this? I'm looking for something like the `[t]` option for `tabular`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
Frequency None Carpet Polystyrene Foam gibboard
180       560  322    47.2        428  41.2
950       58.4 45.6   42.8        55.2 48.4
2200      48.4 43.2   44          60   50.8
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \pgfplotstabletypeset [columns/gibboard/.style={column name=Gib board}] {data.txt}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tabular environment is contained in a `begin table` pgfkey and is initially `\begin{tabular}` (see current manual of `pgfplotstable` package, v. 1.12.1, as of (2015/05/02))

If the table should be top-aligned, say `begin table={\begin{tabular}[t]}` as an option to the `\pgfplotstabletypeset` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
Frequency None Carpet Polystyrene Foam gibboard
180       560  322    47.2        428  41.2
950       58.4 45.6   42.8        55.2 48.4
2200      48.4 43.2   44          60   50.8
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \pgfplotstabletypeset [begin table={\begin{tabular}[t]},columns/gibboard/.style={column name=Gib board}] {data.txt}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]